# Using self-pipe, how can I avoid that the event loop stalls on read()?

Tags: c, signals, sus

I am trying to make use of the [self-pipe](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) trick to get a portable implementation (across Solaris, MacOSX, Linux, BSDs) of my application.

So in addition to the two pipes for `stderr` and `stdout` which I am using to fetch the output of the forked child (I use no `exec` in the child, the child executes the same code as the parent), I have the pipe for signals (`enum {SIG_PIPE, STDOUT_PIPE, STDERR_PIPE, MAX_PIPE}` provides the symbolic names).

- `O_NONBLOCK` is set on the pipes, prior to calling `handle_child_output()`.
- the child has the write ends of the `stderr` and `stdout` pipes and continues using `printf()` and friends, effectively writing to each respective pipe (`setvbuf` is used to turn off buffering inside the child).

The code to follow is a bit lengthy, as is the self-pipe trick in general. It is already the condensed form. So let me try to explain what should happen and where it gets stuck.

I *need* to collect the exit status and I have to be able to find out whether the child terminated with a signal or via exit. The handling of those conditions is in place elsewhere. What's relevant is that `handle_child_output()` returns the exit code of the child inside the `int` pointed to by `pstatus`.

The outer `do`-`while` loop in `handle_child_output()` will set up the `FD_SET` to use in the `select` call. It adds the signal pipe read-end plus the read-ends of the `stderr` and `stdout` pipe from the child.

Then the `if(FD_ISSET(fds[SIG_PIPE], &rd))` checks whether the signal pipe contains anything new and drains it, handling any potential signals.

The `for` loop after that loops through the remaining file descriptors to see whether anything is pending and then handles by parroting what it gets on the parent's respective `stdio` channel.

The read call in that second loop is where it gets stalled.

The symptom is that the parent is stuck in the read call:

```
(gdb) bt 1
#0  0x00007f2daaa9e530 in __read_nocancel () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

It's as if there is a race condition between reading the signal pipe and the other pipes. The child seems to have exited already by the time the file descriptors get inspected and consequently ends up as a zombie, because the parent is still stuck in the `read()` and will never reach one of the `wait()` calls.

What am I doing wrong? Would it be legit to add an `if(exitloop) break;` before the `for` loop to break out of the outer `do`-`while` loop? It seems to me that this could leave unread content in the pipes, no?

---

```
#define __MAX__(x,y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
int childpid;
typedef enum { READ, WRITE, BOTH } pipefd_type_t;

static void avoid_zombie(int* pstatus)
{
    int temp;
    pstatus = (pstatus) ? pstatus : &temp;
    if(0 > childpid && 0 != childpid) {
        kill(childpid, SIGKILL); /* kill the child */
    }
    wait(pstatus); /* wait to avoid lingering zombies */
}

static void select_signal_handler(int sig)
{
    int savedErrno = errno;
    const int sigw = sig;
    if(0 > write(sigpipe[WRITE], &sigw, sizeof(sigw))) {
        avoid_zombie(NULL);
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
    }
    errno = savedErrno;
}

void handle_child_output(int *pstatus)
{
    enum {SIG_PIPE, STDOUT_PIPE, STDERR_PIPE, MAX_PIPE};
    fd_set rd;
    int ready, n = 0, fds[MAX_PIPE];
    size_t i, exitloop, sigint;
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct {
        int sig;
        struct sigaction oldsa;
    } old_sigactions[3];
    old_sigactions[0].sig = SIGINT;
    old_sigactions[1].sig = SIGCHLD;
    old_sigactions[2].sig = SIGQUIT;
    /* fds have been initialized at this point (read-ends) */

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(old_sigactions)/sizeof(old_sigactions[0]); i++) {
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
        sa.sa_handler = select_signal_handler;
        if(0 > sigaction(old_sigactions[i].sig, &sa, &old_sigactions[i].oldsa)) {
            avoid_zombie(pstatus);
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
        }
    }

    do {
        sigint = 0;
        exitloop = 0;
        FD_ZERO(&rd);
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_PIPE; i++) {
            if(fds[i] >= FD_SETSIZE) {
                avoid_zombie(pstatus);
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
            }
            FD_SET(fds[i], &rd);
            n = __MAX__(n, fds[i]);
        }

        while(0 > (ready = select(n+1, &rd, NULL, NULL, NULL)))
            if (EINTR == errno) continue;

        if(0 > ready) {
            avoid_zombie(pstatus);
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
        }

        if(FD_ISSET(fds[SIG_PIPE], &rd)) {
            do { /* drain the signal pipe */
                int sig = -1;
                if(0 > read(fds[SIG_PIPE], &sig, sizeof(sig))) {
                    if(EAGAIN == errno)
                        break;
                    else {
                        avoid_zombie(pstatus);
                        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
                    }
                }
                switch(sig) {
                case SIGINT:
                    if(0 > childpid && 0 != childpid) {
                        kill(childpid, SIGINT); /* pass to child */
                        wait(pstatus);
                    }
                    sigint++; exitloop++;
                    break;
                case SIGCHLD:
                    exitloop++;
                    break;
                }
            } while(1);
        }

        for(i = STDOUT_PIPE; i < MAX_PIPE; i++) {
            if(FD_ISSET(fds[i], &rd)) {
                do {
                    const size_t max_tries = 5;
                    char buf[0x1000];
                    ssize_t bytesWritten, bytesRead = read(fds[i], buf, sizeof(buf));
                    if(0 == bytesRead)
                        break;
                    int outchan = STDERR_FILENO;
                    if(0 > bytesRead) {
                        /* Retry (inner do-while loop) if we get an EAGAIN */
                        if(EAGAIN == errno) break;
                        /* fatal error */
                        avoid_zombie(pstatus);
                        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
                    }
                    if(STDOUT_PIPE == i)
                        outchan = STDOUT_FILENO;
                    bytesWritten = write(outchan, buf, bytesRead);
                    if(0 > bytesWritten) {
                        /* Retry if we get an EAGAIN */
                        if(EAGAIN == errno) {
                            size_t tries;
                            for(tries = 0; tries < max_tries; tries++) {
                                bytesWritten = write(outchan, buf, bytesRead);
                                if((0 > bytesWritten) && (EAGAIN == errno))
                                    continue;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(0 > bytesWritten) {
                            avoid_zombie(pstatus);
                            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
                        }
                    }
                    if(bytesWritten < bytesRead) {
                        const ssize_t bytesToWrite = bytesRead - bytesWritten;
                        /* try to write the remainder */
                        ssize_t bytesWritten2 = write(outchan, &buf[bytesWritten], bytesToWrite);
                        if((0 > bytesWritten2) || (bytesWritten2 != bytesToWrite)) {
                            /* fatal error */
                            avoid_zombie(pstatus);
                            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
                        }
                    }
                } while(1);
            }
        }
    } while(0 == exitloop);
    /* restore old signal handlers */
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(old_sigactions)/sizeof(old_sigactions[0]); i++) {
        if (sigaction(old_sigactions[i].sig, &old_sigactions[i].oldsa, NULL) == -1) {
            avoid_zombie(pstatus);
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* actual code also shows error etc */
        }
    }
    avoid_zombie(pstatus);
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I *am* writing into the write-end of the signal pipe in the parent (see the signal handler shown in the code). New books, not just links from 22 years ago mention this still as the most portable way. I noticed other code bases have "modules" for the respective OS-specific mechanisms, though. E.g. `nginx`. If you have a better idea that will work across the platforms mentioned, please answer. All of the shown code is running in the parent. TLPI, a relatively recent book, also makes a mention of the technique.

Comment: I've withdrawn my comment.  I've not come across the trick which probably means I haven't read Stevens carefully enough. I stand by "we probably don't have enough code to know what's going wrong".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: which part of the code would you like to see? The context is clear and the setup outside of the given code has been duly described. I didn't want to post a wall of code. Normally one gets already comments about "reduce to the absolute necessary" with less than half of the amount of lines I gave.

Comment: 'Tis tricky.  I'd like to see an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). What you've got is a large block of code and it is intimidating; that's probably why no-one else has broached your question. I don't know what I need to do to make the code you show into a program I can test. For example, you have an uninitialized local array `fds[MAX_PIPE]`; you don't seem to have any `pipe()` or `fork()` calls, so I don't know what I'm not being shown.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'll update it tomorrow then. And the array is initialized before the function is called (as per the comment in the function). The problem with the two types of examples - that I was referring to in my previous comment also - is that it doesn't necessarily reproduce the issue, as is so often the case with race conditions. The child in my program of course produces output based on some processing, but I am not free to make the code available. I'll see what I can do, though.